# "emcc" command does not recognized

Tags: javascript, opencv, emscripten, asm.js

I'm having issue with building this demo.
https://github.com/kakukogou/opencvjs_demo_segmentation

When i cd into this folder and run make command i get this error message:

```
/bin/sh: 1: emcc: not found  
make: *** [segmentation] Error 127
```

This is how make file looks like.

```
segmentation: ../src/segmentation.cpp ../src/export.cpp  
    mkdir -p $(OBJDIR)  
    emcc \  
    ../src/segmentation.cpp \  
    ../src/export.cpp \  
    -I $(OPENCV_INSTALL_DIR)/include \  
    $(OPENCV_INSTALL_DIR)/lib/libopencv_core.so \   
    $(OPENCV_INSTALL_DIR)/lib/libopencv_imgproc.so \  
    -s EXPORTED_FUNCTIONS="['_on_mouse', '_on_init', '_on_process']" \  
    -O3 \  
    --llvm-lto 1 \  
    --closure 1 \  
    -s PRECISE_F32=1 \  
    -s FORCE_ALIGNED_MEMORY=1 \  
    -s TOTAL_MEMORY=306777216 \  
    -o ./bin/segmentation.js  

clean:  
    rm ./bin/*.js ./bin/*.mem
```

Is there any issue with my environment variables.
What is the proper way to compile this ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For whatever reason default path configurations in **.emscripten** does not enable emcc in terminal. so i manually set the EMSCRIPTEN_ROOT in **/etc/environment** and now it recognizes the emcc command in terminal.

Answer (score 4):

For Windows, in 'emsdk' folder (downloaded from ' git clone https://github.com/emscripten-core/emsdk.git ') run :

```
./emsdk activate latest --permanent
```

Answer (score 2):

this works for me 
adding
`source ./emsdk_env.sh` 
to `.bashrc` or `.zshrc` file

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 2):

Encounter same problem in **window 11**

In my case there was problem with path of `EMSDK`

After running `emsdk_env.bat`

I have check path in environment variable and I found it was `E:/emsdk`

Then I have changed it to `E:\emsdk`

Now working fine for me

Answer (score 0):

You have to make the environment manually, try this

```
source /emsdk/emsdk_env.sh
```